# CFData vs CFString

Tags: cocoa, cfstring, cfdata

I have a `CFMutableDictionaryRef`, part of which in debugger is:

> ```
> "device-id" = <72270000>;
>
> model = <474d4120 39353000>;
>
> "vendor-id" = <86800000>;
> ```

Now I can get value of the key `model` using `CFDataRef` which returns string like "GMA 950", as compared to the value above.

But I cannot get value of `"vendor-id"`using same method so I try with `CFString`, which returns `<86800000>` instead of a string. So how to retreive correct value of the vendor id (which I already know should return 0x8086 for Intel) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it:

have to format the string retreived with CFString as:

```
NSString *id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%X",*((UInt32*)CFDataGetBytePtr(cfstr))];
```